# Zigbit ATZB-24-A2 SMD to DIP socket

Tags: atmel, zigbee

I'm looking for solution how to mount Zigbit ATZB to prototype board without making individual PCB with pin outputs. Do you know any socket adapter with pins spacing like this? Or any other solution for this?

Comment: A more detailed description of your problem would help.

Comment: I meant typical prototype board with 2.54 mm pitch. Like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/400_points_breadboard.jpg

Comment: Welcome to ee.se. Please post a link to the datasheet of the specific part; it helps people to understand the question more easily, and it avoids any possibility of ambiguity. Also, please update information into your question, rather than leave it in comments. That helps people understand the question more quickly and easily too. It also means your question stands alone, and comments can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question lacks a specification of the prototype boards pin pitch, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

You could use a pitch adapter from the Zigbit ATZB's 1mm pitch to 2.54mm, like this:
http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=3800027